# Variable zero in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm facing one really weird problem

```
// Update the service
stage "Update Service"
def SERVICE_NAME = "currency-converter-search-srv"
def TASK_FAMILY = "currency-converter-search"
def TASK_REVISION = sh "aws --region us-east-1 ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition currency-converter-search | jq .taskDefinition.revision"
def DESIRED_COUNT = sh "aws --region us-east-1 ecs describe-services --services ${SERVICE_NAME} | jq .services[0].desiredCount"
if (DESIRED_COUNT == 0) {
  DESIRED_COUNT = 1
}
sh "aws --region us-east-1 ecs update-service --cluster default --service ${SERVICE_NAME} --task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY}:${TASK_REVISION} --desired-count ${DESIRED_COUNT}"
```

this script fails and here below the log:

```
[Pipeline] stage (Update Service)
Entering stage Update Service
Proceeding
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ jq .taskDefinition.revision
+ aws --region us-east-1 ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition currency-converter-search
13
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ jq .services[0].desiredCount
+ aws --region us-east-1 ecs describe-services --services currency-converter-search-srv
0
[Pipeline] sh
[workspace] Running shell script
+ aws --region us-east-1 ecs update-service --cluster default --service currency-converter-search-srv --task-definition currency-converter-search:0 --desired-count 1

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: revision must be between 1 and 2147483647
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE
```

The reason is because `TASK_REVISION` variable is `0` but according to how it is processed is not zero but `13`. do you know why this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign the result of `sh` to a variable.

`sh` doesn't return anything meaningful...  I think there's an [issue for this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26133), but there's no fix yet

The workaround seems to be to redirect the result to a file, then read that file

Comment: But if I execute this command in the console `aws --region us-east-1 ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition currency-converter-search | jq .taskDefinition.revision`, it returns me a result so it is sh that it not return anything

Comment: That's what I said.  `sh` doesn't return anything

Comment: Yes thank you a lot. I was struggling to understand the reason